# Have to cast value in assignment

Tags: c++, c, casting

I've got some c++ code that's requiring me to cast an immediate in an assignment statement. The casting makes the code more difficult to read and I was hoping there was a way around this.

```
uint64_t shifted_val = (uint64_t)1 << 50;
```

If I write this code without the cast, `shifted_val` gets set to 0, I assume because it's treating the `1` immediate as a 32-bit value. Is there something I'm missing so that I can write this without casting?

Comment: Write `(1ull << 50)`

Comment: The constant `1` is of type `int` (however many bits it happens to be), so `1 << 50` is also of type `int`. And in fact `1 << 50` has undefined behavior unless `int` is wider than 50 bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to adopt a habit of performing the calculations within the recipient variable itself

```
uint64_t shifted_val = 1;
shifted_val <<= 50;
```

This will solve the issue naturally, without requiring you to hardcode additional type references into the expression (like type casts or type-specific suffixes).

Comment: I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
uint64_t shifted_val = 1ull << 50;
```

If you think the syntax is also close to casting then you can do:

```
uint64_t a = 1;
uint64_t shifted_val = a << 50;
```

Comment: The parentheses are harmless but unnecessary.

Comment: Deleted parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

The constant needs to be treated as a 64 bit value, so there needs to be some way of specifying that.

You could specify it as `1ULL`, which tells the compiler the constant is a `unsigned long long`, however that may not necessarily be 64 bit, so you're better off with the cast to be more portable.

Comment: `1ull` is **at least** 64 bits wide, and that's all that's needed.